# How to get the value of selected option from React hooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

I have this React Component like below:

```
const ProductCell = (props) => {
    const [option, setOption] = useState();

    return(
     <div>
        <NativeSelect
            value={option}
            onChange={e => setOption(e.target.value)}
        >

            {props.product.variations.nodes.map(  // here I extracted all the item
                (item, i) => (
                    <option value={item} key={i}>{item.name}</option>  // set option value to item object
                ))
            }
                    
        </NativeSelect>

        <Typography variant="h5" className={classes.title}>
            {option.price}  // I want to update the value of price according to the selected option. 
        </Typography>       // according to the selected option above
     </div>
    )
}
```

I have a `NativeSelect` component which is from React Material-Ui, so basically it is a `Select` html tag. In the code above, what I do is, extract all the element inside `props.product.variations.nodes` and put all the extracted `item` and put each of the element into a `<options/>` tag.

The Json object for item will look like this:

```
"variations": {
    "nodes": [
        {
            "id": "someId",
            "name": "abc1234",
            "variationId": 24,
            "price": "$100.00"
        },
        {
           .. another ID, name,variation and price
        }
    ]
}
```

As you can see, I targeting the part of `id`, `name` , `variationId` and `price` as an object. Therefore each `<option/>` tag will present with `item.name` as the presentation to user. So far in this part having no problem, let say having 5 variations, and can present all of them.

**What I want to do is:**

I want to update the value of price under the `<Typography />`  component. Example, user selected 3rd options in the `Select`, I want to update the `price` value of the 3rd item in `<Typography />` .

**What I tried:**

I create a react hooks `const [option, setOption] = useState();` , then when `handleChange`,  I `setOption()` with `event.target.value` in `NativeSelect` component . Therefore the `value` of `<option />` tag  is set as `item` object.

Lastly, I get the `price` value from the hooks in the `Typography` section.

**But what I get is:**

The price value is `undefined` in console log. So I can't get the value of `option.price`.

and this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'price' of undefined

**Question:**

How can I get the `option.price` value(which I expect it is same with `item.price`) outside the `NativeSelect` component in my above example?

I tried my best to explain based on what I understand by this time being. So any help will be well appreciated.

**Update:**

Here is what I got when console log the `item` object in `variation.node.map()` section and `data` object inside `onHandleChanged` section, but also produce the same result:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set a default selected option on your `ProductCell` component. Also your `onChange` handler will receive a `string` instead of an `object` when you access the value on `event.target.value`.

From the [docs](https://material-ui.com/api/native-select/#props)

> `function(event: object) => void event`: The event source of the callback. You can pull out the new value by accessing `event.target.value` (string).

`event.target.value` will be a string even though you pass the `value` as `object` on `NativeSelect` component.

What you might want to do? Don't set the current selected item as an `object`, instead use the `id` and have a function that look-ups the item using the current selected `id`.

Check the code below.

```js
const ProductCell = (props) => {
  const { variations } = props.product;
  const { nodes } = variations;

  // we're setting the first node's id as selected value
  const [selectedId, setSelectedId] = useState(nodes[0].id);

  const getSelectedPrice = () => {
    // finds the node from the current `selectedId`
    // and returns `price`
    const obj = nodes.find((node) => node.id === selectedId);
    return obj.price;
  };

  function onChange(event) {
    // event.target.value will be the id of the current
    // selected node
    setSelectedId(parseInt(event.target.value));
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <NativeSelect value={selectedId} onChange={onChange}>
        {nodes.map((item, i) => (
          <option value={item.id} key={i}>
            {item.name}
          </option>
        ))}
      </NativeSelect>
      <Typography variant="h5">{getSelectedPrice()}</Typography>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Also notice that were passing the `id` as a `value` prop on each of our `option`s.

```js
<option value={item.id} key={i}>
```

And how we now display the `price`, we're calling our `getSelectedPrice()`.

[image: Edit gallant-agnesi-289ei]

---

**Update**

I thought a better solution. I realized that you can set your `selected` state as an object and on your `onChange` handler given the `id` from `event.target.value` find the item on `nodes` and set that as your new `selected` state.

```js
const ProductCell = (props) => {
  const { variations } = props.product;
  const { nodes } = variations;

  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(nodes[0]);

  function onChange(event) {
    const value = parseInt(event.target.value);
    setSelected(nodes.find((node) => node.id === value));
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <NativeSelect value={selected.id} onChange={onChange}>
        {nodes.map((item, i) => (
          <option value={item.id} key={i}>
            {item.name}
          </option>
        ))}
      </NativeSelect>
      <Typography variant="h5">{selected.price}</Typography>
    </div>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit quizzical-nash-mg4bc]

Comment: One thing I need to ask, for this 2 line of codes `const { variations } = props.product;
  const { nodes } = variations;` at the beginning, is this how we destruct the array inside another array?? Suppose to be `props.product.variations.map(the item inside)`, but we make it to `{variations} = props.product` and `{nodes} = variation`, this 2 link is quite confuse me

Comment: That's how you destruct an `object` to get a `value`, it's called `destructuring assignment`. Though it works for `array` too, in our code above were dealing with `object`s.